# bitcoinrpc calls return nothing

Tags: python, django, json-rpc, bitcoind

I am using bitcoind in my project and when I deploy it on my server bitcoind works strange. I use this lib to work with rpc https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc. On local dev server everything is fine but when I deploy it to vps it stops return data. The data is empty. I made some tests like this:

```
bitcoin.conf file:
server=1
rpcuser=myuser
rpcpassword=mypassword
rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8332
```

some view.py:

```
def btc_rpc_connect(config):

    rpc_server_url = ("http://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}").format(
        user=config.rpc_user,
        password=config.rpc_pass,
        host=config.rpc_host,
        port=config.rpc_port
    )
    rpc_conn = AuthServiceProxy(rpc_server_url)
    return rpc_conn

user = request.user
# getting rpc settings from db
config = ProjectSettings.objects.get(id=1)
rpc_connection = btc_rpc_connect(config)
btc_address = rpc_connection.getnewaddress(user.username)
```

I also tried to test from django's ./manage.py shell and entered this code manually. The fact is works on dev server and i have an address in `btc_address`, but on vps `btc_address` is empty! Please help me. Can it happen because of permission troubles? Anyways bitcoind accept the connection and do not return authentification exception, but no reaction to any command.

But if I use it from console:

```
bitcoin-cli getnewaddress
```

it works fine and give me an address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omg that was bug in the repo, and I fixed it locally several month ago and forgot about that! If you have the same problem you can mannually edit `lib/python2.7/site-packages/bitcoinrpc/authproxy.py` delete `else:` on 146 line and move out `return response['result']` from `elif` block like in here: https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc/commit/8c0114bfbf7650d40a88b20d1e16ff79d768f3a9

Another way is delete python-bitcoinrpc:

```
pip uninstall python-bitcoinrpc
```

And reinstall correct version:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc.git
```

Hope they will fix it in repo soon.